# Jquery modal form store data in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm using jQuery modal form [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) to add users as is in default jQuery example.

My question is how to add all users from created table in database when click on button "Add to DB".

I don't wont to add users to database in same time when I add them to html table, I want to add them later all together.

Stackoverflow helped me a lot and this is first time I can't find answer, so please help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Read all records from HTML table and pass Json object array to Code Behind -> insert into DB.